# Date format Ggplot2 linegraph R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, linegraph, formatdatetime

I want to output date in 2018-03-28 format. When I am trying to do that, I get only dots in the line graph:
[image]

When using as.Date or strptime (it doesn't matter), It gives only: jan, feb, mar, apr. But the lines are working:
[image]

This is my code for get the lines working with jan, feb, mar.

```
  output$shotAnalyse2 <- renderPlot({


  head(rsShotResult)


  if(input$shotAnalyse2ShotType == "free_throw"){
    position <- 0
    updateSelectInput(session, "shotAnalyse2Position", selected = 0)
  } else{
    position <- input$shotAnalyse2Position
  }
  ggplot(rsShotResult[rsShotResult$fullname %in% input$shotAnalyse2Players
                      &
                        as.Date(rsShotResult$startdate) <= input$shotAnalyse2Date[2]
                      &
                        as.Date(rsShotResult$startdate) >= input$shotAnalyse2Date[1]
                      &
                        rsShotResult$value3 == position
                      & 
                        rsShotResult$value4 == input$shotAnalyse2ShotType
                      , ],
         aes(x = strptime(starttime, format="%Y-%m-%d"),
             y = percentage)) +
    geom_line(aes(colour = as.character(accountid))) +
     geom_point(aes(colour = as.character(accountid))) +
    xlab("starttime") +
    scale_colour_manual(
      values = palette("default"),
      name = "Players",
      breaks = rsShotResult$accountid
    )
```

When running the command: `dput(head(rsShotResult))`
I get this result:

```
structure(list(accountid = c(22, 22, 27, 28, 28, 30), firstname = c("Henk", 
"Henk", "Tim", "Dean", "Dean", "Max"), lastname = c("Wilders", 
"Wilders", "Sneijder", "Babel", "Babel", "Pele"), starttime = c("2017-12-13", 
"2018-03-09", "2017-12-13", "2017-12-13", "2018-03-09", "2017-12-13"
), value = c(16, 7, 41, 7, 19, 16), value2 = c(23, 10, 47, 16, 
20, 20), value3 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), value4 = c("free_throw", 
"free_throw", "free_throw", "free_throw", "free_throw", "free_throw"
), startdate = c("2017-12-13", "2018-03-09", "2017-12-13", "2017-12-13", 
"2018-03-09", "2017-12-13"), fullname = c("Henk Wilders", "Henk Wilders", 
"Tim Sneijder", "Dean Babel", "Dean Babel", "Max Pele"
), percentage = c(69.5652173913043, 70, 87.2340425531915, 43.75, 
95, 80), points = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_)), .Names = c("accountid", "firstname", "lastname", 
"starttime", "value", "value2", "value3", "value4", "startdate", 
"fullname", "percentage", "points"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the result of `dput(head(rsShotResult))`? You might also try `your_plot + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d")`.

Comment: I editted my post with de dput command. Scale_x_date doesn't work on the whole plot because it formats jan, feb, mar to 2018-01-01, 2018-02-01, 2018-03-01

Comment: Regarding having only points but not lines, are you sure those IDs have more than one observation? At least in the sample data you provided, IDs 22 and 28 yielded lines because they have two dates each, but IDs 27 and 30 only made points, because there's no second observation for either of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this

```
#convert to class date
rsShotResult$starttime <- as.Date(rsShotResult$starttime)

ggplot(rsShotResult, aes(starttime, percentage, col = as.factor(accountid))) +
 geom_point() +
 geom_line() +
 scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d",
              breaks = df$starttime)
```

[image]

---

The problem with your first plot is that `rsShotResult$starttime` is of class `character`. While plotting, you should have read the following

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Hence you could also have used this code:

```
ggplot(rsShotResult, aes(starttime, percentage, col = as.factor(accountid))) +
 geom_point() +
 geom_line(aes(group = accountid))
```

[image]

However, this results in a discrete scale and I'd not recommend to plot your data this way since date is continuous. But that is up to you of course.

I hope this helps.

**data**

```
rsShotResult <- structure(list(accountid = c(22, 22, 27, 28, 28, 30), firstname = c("Henk", 
"Henk", "Tim", "Dean", "Dean", "Max"), lastname = c("Wilders", 
"Wilders", "Sneijder", "Babel", "Babel", "Pele"), starttime = c("2017-12-13", 
"2018-03-09", "2017-12-13", "2017-12-13", "2018-03-09", "2017-12-13"
), value = c(16, 7, 41, 7, 19, 16), value2 = c(23, 10, 47, 16, 
20, 20), value3 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), value4 = c("free_throw", 
"free_throw", "free_throw", "free_throw", "free_throw", "free_throw"
), startdate = c("2017-12-13", "2018-03-09", "2017-12-13", "2017-12-13", 
"2018-03-09", "2017-12-13"), fullname = c("Henk Wilders", "Henk Wilders", 
"Tim Sneijder", "Dean Babel", "Dean Babel", "Max Pele"
), percentage = c(69.5652173913043, 70, 87.2340425531915, 43.75, 
95, 80), points = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_)), .Names = c("accountid", "firstname", "lastname", 
"starttime", "value", "value2", "value3", "value4", "startdate", 
"fullname", "percentage", "points"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @jurh Glad I could help.